# How can i manually reindex solr using sunspot?

Tags: couchdb, sunspot, reindex

I have couchdb. Sunspot was correctly indexing everything. But the Solr server crashed. I need to reindex the whole thing. rake sunspot:reindex wont work as it is tigthly coupled with active record. sunspot.index(model.all) didnt work. the solr core says 0 indexed docs even after doing that. is there a way out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I was looking for was this:

Post.index!(Model.all)

There was something bad happening when I tried to index assuming that batch commits would happen automatically. Any way this worked totally fine for me.

Answer (score 14):

Post.solr_reindex

There are a number of options that can be passed to solr_reindex. The same options as to index; from the [documentation](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb#L196)

index in batches of 50, commit after each

```
Post.index
```

index all rows at once, then commit

```
Post.index(:batch_size => nil)
```

index in batches of 50, commit when all batches complete

```
Post.index(:batch_commit => false)
```

include the associated +author+ object when loading to index

```
Post.index(:include => :author)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I was looking for was index!() function. Batch commits was not working somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I usually write below command to index models. It works perfectly every time.

**For a Model i.e. (Post)**

```
Sunspot.index Post.all
```

**For a Model row i.e. (Post.where(id: 5))**

```
Sunspot.index Post.where(id: 5)
```

It will work.

Cheers!